# Unable to send data to Thingspeak using ESP8266 and STM32 Nucleo

Tags: stm32, esp8266, mbed, nucleo

I am using ARM's mbed compiler to program my STM32 Nucleo. I am also using an ESP8266 as my WiFi module.

My connections are as such:

- Rx of the ESP8266 is connected to D8 on the Nucleo.
- Tx of the ESP8266 is connected to D2 on the Nucleo.
- Gnd of the ESP8266 to the gnd on the board.
  All other pins of the ESP8266 are connected to 3.3V on the Nucleo.

The following is my mbed code:

```
#include "mbed.h"  

Serial esp(D8, D2);  
DigitalOut myled(LED1);

void flush(void) {  
  while (esp.readable()) {  
    (void)esp.getc();  
  }    
}  

int main() {  
  esp.baud (115200);
  char server[]="GET /update?key=NR************2Z&field1=7";
  flush();  

  esp.printf("AT+RST\r\n");
  wait(2);  

  esp.printf("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n");  
  wait(3);  

  esp.printf("AT+CWJAP=\"Harsha\",\"*****\"\r\n"); 
  wait(3);  

  esp.printf("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n");
  wait(3); 

  esp.printf("AT+CIPSTART=4,\"TCP\",\"184.106.153.149\",80\r\n");  
  wait(3);

  esp.printf("AT+CIPSEND=4,%d\r\n", sizeof(server)+2);  
  wait(2);

  esp.printf("%s\r\n", server); 
  wait(3);

  esp.printf("AT+CIPCLOSE\r\n"); 

  while(1) {  
    myled = 1;
    wait(0.1);

    myled = 0;
    wait(0.1);
   } 

  return 0;  
}
```

I am able to connect to my WiFi hotspot which means there is no problem with the connection. But the data I pass is not updated in Thingspeak at all. I have also tried it including HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 in the 'server' string, still nothing. Am I missing something?

Comment: How can you be sure your AT commands work? I don't see any error checking at all

Comment: I was trying to avoid an error check with a long delay. I know its not useful but is error checking that important? I have seen other codes where AT commands are just blindly sent.

Comment: Delays won't do anything useful if the device answers ERROR in a few msecs...

Comment: Okay, lets assume there was an error, its still not gonna say what error it is. It means that there is something wrong with the AT commands somewhere. Thats what I want opinions for.

Comment: These AT commands must be specified somewhere. For instance, the response might be OK or ERROR for simple commands, and might include an error code for some commands. What does the datasheet say? (e.g. on this module AT+RST should reply with "ready" at some point from what I saw using 2 minutes of googling)

Comment: It responds with a ready, version name and its vendor details etc. to be specific. All that is fine. It is even connecting to my hotspot as I have stated in the question. The problem is the data isnt going to Thingspeak. I am sure some body else should have had similar issues. Hence I am asking for their opinions and experiences. If your googling what AT+RST gives, then I am pretty sure you have never used the module before, right?

Comment: Blindly sending AT commands while not reading the manual is asking for trouble. I have tried to point you in the correct direction (RTFM). I have never used *this* module nor do I have any intent to do so. Oddly enough, I have just had the same discussion with a customer and they would do everything to not read the manual ... while still complaining things wouldn't work. Letting other people do the debugging for you won't lead you very far. Sorry, but you have to do your homework (what is the module answering?).

Comment: You may need to switch the ESP out of command mode. On old Hayes modems we had to wait about 200mS for command mode to timeout before we sent data. We switched back using +++. On some devices there is a mode pin. The protocol may have changed, check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by increasing the delay for establishing the Wifi connection after the reset. For those who might find this helpful, the working code is as below:

```
#include "mbed.h"  

Serial esp(D8, D2);  
DigitalOut myled(LED1);

void flush(void) {  
    while (esp.readable()) {  
        (void)esp.getc();  
    }    
}

char server[]="GET /update?api_key=9FL*********C2&field2=";

int main() {  
    int x=7;
    esp.baud(115200);
    flush();  

    esp.printf("AT+RST\r\n"); /* reset module */  
    wait(2);  
    flush();  

    esp.printf("AT+CWMODE=3\r\n");  
    wait(1);  
    flush();  

    // The huge delay was key to obtaining the IP address, so that further commands don't interfere with the ongoing process
    esp.printf("AT+CWJAP=\"Harsha\",\"*******\"\r\n"); /* configure as access point */  
    wait(20);  
    flush();  

    esp.printf("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n");
    wait(5);
    flush();  
    //response();
    esp.printf("AT+CIPSTART=0,\"TCP\",\"api.thingspeak.com\",80\r\n");  
    wait(5);
    flush();  
    //response();

    esp.printf("AT+CIPSEND=0,%d\r\n", sizeof(server)+15);  
    wait(3);
    flush();  
    //response();

    esp.printf("%s", server);
    esp.printf("%d", x);
    esp.printf(" HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n");
    wait(2);
    flush(); 

    while(1) {  
        //To indicate completion
        myled = 1;
        wait(0.1);
        myled = 0;
        wait(0.1);
    }   
    return 0;  
}
```